# How does RoleGuard works in Nest JS? with JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, roles, nestjs

The  feature I am working on is that the system should determine a correct type of user and allow appropriate permissions after successful login and what I had in mind is to use RoleGuard feature of nest JS.

But I can't seem to figure out how this RoleGuard really works.And can't seem to make it work.

I wanted to allow user with specific rules to access some endpoints , like only user with admin role is allowed to get all list of users.

What seem to be the issue ? Anyone has an idea ? I have provided snippets below. And upon requesting should I'll just be adding role in the request body ? or it would be good if Ill get the current logged user and determine the role ? Thank you.


 
**Here is my user data which has the role:**

```
"id": 11, {
    "role": "admin",
    "username": "myadmin@test.com",
    "created": "2020-03-18T02:30:04.000Z",
    "updated": "2020-03-18T03:02:12.000Z"
}
```

## SampleCode

```
 import { JwtAuthGuard } from '../../auth/jwt-auth.guard';
    import { RolesGuard } from '../../common/guards/roles.guard';
    import { Roles } from '../common/decorators/roles.decorator';

    @Controller('user')
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
    export class UserController {
      constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

      @Get()
      @Roles('admin')
      findAll(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
        return this.usersService.findAll();
      }
```

## RoleGuard

```
 export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
        const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
        console.log('roles:', roles);
        if (!roles) {
          return true;
        }
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const user = request.user;
        const hasRole = () => user.roles.some(role => roles.indexOf(role) > -1);
        console.log('hasRole', hasRole);

        return user && user.roles && hasRole();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To this code works you need to add User obj into request context using an AuthGuard.

First off you don`t need a JwtAuthGuard if you not implement another things the Standard AuthGuard do, Adding JwtAuthGuard into UseGuards decorator mades a overwrite of default AuthGuard and if you not adding the user obj into request obj inside of JwtAuthGuard code, the RolesGuard not will work correctly.

### Standard Approach

If you see the [source code](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/6d9c71fa04e5c16480ba0b7e7671e43918dd9ff4/lib/auth.guard.ts)
into the line 48 the attaches the user obj into request obj. After seeing this it`s simply.. just add into @UseGuards decorator the AuthGuard('jwt'),RolesGuards like that

```
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { RolesGuard } from '../../common/guards/roles.guard';
import { Roles } from '../common/decorators/roles.decorator';

@Controller('user')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), RolesGuard)
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Get()
  @Roles('admin')
  findAll(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }
```

Doing that the Standard Approach to RolesGuards wil runs correctly...
Now if you doing a different things and need a custom AuthGuard.. You need to add the User Obj returned of the validate function of JwtStrategy Class. Like that:

```
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
    handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: ExecutionContext) {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        request.user = user;
        return user;
    }
}
```